# Import caffe error after using sudo apt install caffe-cuda

Tags: python, python-3.x, caffe

How do I import caffe in Python 3 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS after `sudo apt install caffe-cuda` ([link](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html))?

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't add caffe to your python path. The neccessary command is

```
 export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/caffe/python:$PYTHONPATH
```

You can find detailed information [here](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html)

Comment: It installs a binary in /usr/bin. I tried `import caffe` in Python 3 from that directory, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: As far as I recall, there should be a directory, containing a file named "python". this is precisely what you need to add to the Pythonpath to then import caffe, as you already tried.

Comment: There is a python file in /usr/bin, but `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin:$PYTHONPATH` also doesn't help.

Comment: Ok, so I don't have the repo on my computer, so I can't tell you the path, but the file you are including obviously isn't working.  Try running " find / -name python" . I'm guessing you'll find some file by the name of python in a folder(/subfolder of  folder) called caffe. That's the one you need to add